# Is the sum of two sub sequences a sub sequence of the sum of two sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\left\{snk\right\}$ is a subsequence of $\left\{sn\right\}$ and $\left\{tmk
\right\}$ is a subsequence of $\left\{tn\right\}$ then is it true that $\left\{snk + tmk
\right\}$ is a
subsequence of $\left\{sn + tn\right\}$?

Comment: Question: Is $s_n$ a subsequence of itself? How about if we were to remove just the $1^{st}$ term, is that a sub sequence?

Comment: Sn is always a subsequence of itself.... I am not sure where you are going with removing terms

Comment: @SheresiaGumbs Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Well Lets look at the sequences $s_n=n$ and $t_m=-n$. What happens if we were to keep $s_n$ (that is $s_{n_k}=s_n$) and change $t_{m_k}$ even just a little say take only the even $m$'s?

Comment: @Arbuja I have no idea how to...

Comment: I think this is fairly clear if you draw a picture of two sequences imagine taking arbitrary subsequences of both.  Think about what happens if the subsequences don't line up properly.

Comment: Click on [this mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the sequences defined by $s_{n}=(-1)^{n}$ and $t_{m}=(-1)^{m+1}$. I can pick subsequences such that $s_{n_{k}}=1$ and $t_{m_{k}}=1$ for all $k$ and hence $s_{n_{k}}+t_{m_{k}}=2$ for all $k$. However, $s_n+t_n=(-1)^n+(-1)^{n+1}=0$. What can you conclude?

Comment: thank you! I was trying to prove that it was true; it didn't occur to me to try to find a counterexample!

Comment: @SheresiaGumbs: best advice I can give when tackling a problem is to try fooling around with real examples to build intuition before you sit down and try to prove something.