# How do these properties of subsequences work?

Tags: real-analysis

I do not need a full proof but just an explanation of how these two properties of subsequences work:

a. If $(a_{k_n})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$, then $({a^2}_{k_n})$ is a subsequence of $(a^2_k)$.

b. If $(a_{k_n})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$ and $(b_{l_n})$ is a subsequence of $(b_n)$, then $(a_{k_n}+b_{l_n})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n+b_n)$.

So I think that for a, it would make sense that this is true because all squared values for a sequence will exist as subsequences in the same increasing indices that you take them for no matter if the sequence converges or not.

For b, I think this is also intuitively true because adding two sequences is the same as simply adding each of their respective subsequence together. You again won't be "losing" any members of either subsequence.

I just want to know how I can say these two in a more analytical way but not necessarily a proof.

Comment: These things are sort of obviously true, but it requires a careful definition of sequence and subsequence to prove it with even minimal rigor.

Comment: I didn't bother with the first one because I don't understand what $({a^2}_{k_n})$ means. The second one if false. Take $a=b$ and let'em be the identity function on the natural numbers. Their sum is the sequence of all even numbers (in increasing order). Can you find subsequences of $a$ and $b$ such that their sum doesn't yield any even numbers? [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2267515/55235)'s another counterexample.

Comment: By the way, I concluded the above because I worked from the definitions. The definition is the most powerful entity in mathematics. Not working from the definitions will lead to mistakes (mostly due to human intuition failing) sooner or later.

Comment: Oh it just means that each subsequence value is squared.

Comment: Minor comment: your notation seems strange to me (in a way that contradicts my intuition about sequences and subsequences). If the sequence is indexed $\{a_n\} = \{a_1, a_2, \dots \}$, when you form a subsequence, you're selecting certain values of the index $n$, so it makes more sense (to me) to write $\{a_{n_k}\} = \{a_{n_1}, a_{n_2}, \dots \}$.

Comment: One thing that helps visualize subsequences of, say, real numbers: remember that a sequence is just a list of values of a function whose domain consists of the natural numbers. So, $a_n = f(n)$, where $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then a subsequence is constructed by *pre*composing this with an *injective* function $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, where $g(k) = n$. So $f(g(k))$ corresponds to the $k$th term in the subsequence, i.e., $a_{n_k}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement b isn't necessarily true.  Let $a_n = (-1)^n, b_n=(-1)^{n+1}$.  Then $\forall n \in \Bbb N~(a_n+b_n=0)$ but unless you're taking the same subset of indices for $a_n$ and $b_n$, it's not necessarily that case that $a_{k_n}+b_{l_n}=0$.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. I was thinking that you had to have the same indexed subsequence for both so that was why I thought differently. What about for a if I may ask?

Comment: a is true.  There's only one sequence in sight so you don't have to worry about different subsequences of different sequences.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought too but is there any way to say this in a more analytical way?

Comment: Sure.  It should flow directly from whatever definition of subsequence you're using.